# How to add a VM Server to a VM Domain when the host is not on that domain

Tags: virtualization, active-directory

## Update

It may be clear that my knowledge of networking is limited.  If you could explain things in basic terms or point me to additional reading I would be greatful.

## Original Question

I have created A VM running Windows Server 2008 R2, using VMWare Player.  I have configured this as a domain controller running a Windows Server 2008 domain.

I have also created another VM running Windows Server 2008 R2.

The HOST machine is using Windows 7 Professional 64 bit.

When I try to add the second VM into the domain that the first is the DC for it fails as the VM cannot contact the DC.

Simple question really.  What have I missed?  Is it something to do with the configuration on the Host machine?  What do I need to do to enable this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Vmware?  You are using bridged network interfaces right?

Comment: VMWare is **NOT A PRODUCT**, it is a company that makes products.

Comment: @Chris S: +100 on that comment if I could.

Comment: Updated that I am using WMware Player (not ideal) but its free and I have had lots of problems running VMware Server.

Comment: @Zoredache - Yes I am using bridged network.

Answer (score 1):

Are they on the same subnet?  Does your second guest machine use the DC you created as a DNS server?  There shouldn't be much beyond that.

Comment: How do I configure the second guest to use the first as a DNS server?

Comment: Just go to the IPv4 TCP/IP properties screen for the second machine and set the primary DNS server to the IP address of the first machine.  This will work assuming that your machines can see each other on the network.  If not, you'll need to do a bit extra.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I have set that up but I cannot ping the IP of the DNS server from the second guest so I assume they cannot see each other.  What was that bit extra?

Comment: Please provide your the following properties for both machines and we'll check and see if they're on the same subnet: IP Address and Subnet Mask.

Answer (score 1):

> Simple question really. What have I missed?

A network that is properly configured?

Basically what you do can be done ,but both machines need to see each other. Same ethernet subnet (connected virtual network), DNS properly set up etc. Take out the VM and all tings equal the same error would happen. Computers dont magically hook up.

Comment: OK this sound promising, firstly how can I verify they are on the same subnet?  The DC is configured as a DNS server, but surely DNS would be updated when I add the machine to the domain?

Comment: Yes, BUT... to add the computer to a domain it must find the domain, so you must manually set the DNS on the non-added computer to use the domain controller as DNS, obviously. Otherwise it does not know wher eto go for the domain. Or us DHCP and push out the dns of the AD server(s) to the computers.

Comment: OK I see that.  So where would I configure the DNS server for the second guest?  Is that part of the config of the network adapter?  How would I set up DHCP - is that going too far for a small VM scenario (3/4 machines max)?

Comment: Ah - sorry, I pull out of this. If you dont know that and in generally are clueless, I suggest you start reading the documentation from page 1. Active Directory is not something you "just magically put together". DNS / DHCP settings are basic beginner questions. The type you answer a month before you even install AD. Maybe someone else will provide you with a simple "how to do something complex without knowing what you do" howto.

Comment: Appreciate your help thus far.  I can understand how frustrating it can be to try to help people who know very little about a certain topic.